# How to apply an intention to a whole file

Tags: intellij-idea, shortcut

I have a large SQL file where the identifiers are not quoted. IntelliJ IDEA suggest the intention to "Quote identifier". I can do this one by one but this is very cumbersome since I have a lot of different identifiers there (database names, table names, fields).

Using the *Analyze*/*Run inspection by name* command, I can select the "*Identifier should be quoted*" analysis to my whole file. But this analysis does not yield any result for some unknown reason. The result of the analysis is "No suspicious code found".

I also defined an exact scope of the files I want to apply the intention on, but it didn't help - same result.

How can I achieve the application of the intention multiple times at once?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [IntelliJ apply inspection fix throughout entire file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42283791/intellij-apply-inspection-fix-throughout-entire-file)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know how to apply intentions actions in batch (I don't even know if this is possible), but for your problem you can do:

1. Open `Settings > Editor > SQL`. In the general tab, find the option `Identifier quotation` and set it to `Quote`. Click apply.
2. Open your file and reformat it (`Code > Reformat Code` or `Ctrl+Alt+L`).

It should normally add quotes to all the identifiers in the file.