# IntelliJ apply inspection fix throughout entire file

Tags: java, intellij-idea, keyboard-shortcuts, final

In IntelliJ, I have the inspection that checks for variables that can be made `final` turned on so that IntelliJ will highlight those variables and let me quickly add the `final` keyword with <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>Enter</kbd>.

When I open up someone else's code who does not typically use the `final` keyword, I would like a quick way to add `final` to all variables that can be throughout the entire file, or even the entire project, if possible.

Is there any shortcut or some other way to do this easily in IntelliJ?

Comment: I think this can help : https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/206886125-Applying-Suggested-to-the-whole-File

Answer (score 6):

Thank you to [@Mzf](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42283791/intellij-make-all-variables-final-that-can-be/42285289#comment71724617_42283791) for the [link](https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/206886125-Applying-Suggested-to-the-whole-File)!

From that post:

You can achieve this in the current file using the typical <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>Enter</kbd> shortcut when hovering over one such variable that can be made `final`, press <kbd>→</kbd>, and select "Fix all 'Local variable or parameter can be final' problems in file".

[image: Screenshot of solution]

The next item down in that sub-menu is "Run inspection on ...", which will allow you to apply the fix to multiple files in your project.

Answer (score 0):

A non-answer; and backed by my opinion, but in the end, also backed by years of experience thinking about code quality topics:

I know, this is *style*; but still, I think your *style* isn't helpful. To the contrary. So the answer is: don't do that. Don't put `final` on just any variable indiscriminately.

The point is: you want your source code to be precise and verbose ... but also "minimalistic". Keep in mind: each and any character that was written ... needs to be read. And "parsed" and "processed" by the human readers brain.

So you want to balance the things you write down. And thing is: **most** of the time, those `final` keyword will **not** add any value to your source code. Zero.

There are only two places where `final` really makes a difference:

1. Class fields. Those should be `final` as default - because that gets you half-way to *immutable* objects; which is per-se a really good thing. Of course, sometimes you must allow fields to change their value; but as said: that should be the exception.
2. Variables that go into lambdas, anonymous inner classes, ... in other words: variables that **must** be protected from changing; so that it becomes "safe" to use them in a "different" context. But guess what: with Java8, the compiler even learned to detect *effectively* final variables. So you can use them in lambads even without the `final` keyword. So even the fathers of the Java language suggest to you to avoid using that keyword!

But beyond those two cases; there are zillions of places in your code where having `final` **only** contributes to the input that your brain has to digest; without adding value to your program.

Long story short: step back for a second and re-think what you are trying to achieve with this policy.

Finally: and you are sure that you will *remember* to undo your changes to *someone else's* code? As you can see: not everybody supports your style; so you should not only ask how to change other code easily; but also how to *revert* **those** changes back later on. Assume you have to make a few real changes in that source code; and then commit them to your repository - are you really willing to then go in and undo the `final` changes you made manually; whilst ensuring that all other, "real" changes are kept.